# Does the OS resamples the audio player output to fit in specs if they're same?

Tags: macos, audio, resample

If I have the sound card configured for 32-bit floating point sample size with a sample rate of 96kHz, and the audio player (vlc or ffmpeg for the case) is playing a WAV with the same configuration of the sound card, does the operating system resamples the PCM data?

I'm resampling by myself and I want to percibe the difference, so I need the output to don't be resampled.

I'm using Mac OS.

I resampled by myself an audio file and took a WAV as output, I'm playing with the audio player but I don't know if the OS is doing some modifications on the raw PCM data.

Comment: Are you in Lossless mode?

Comment: No, I'm playing WAV files with VLC or ffplay, not with Music.app, and used MIDI Audio configurator to set 96kHz and 32 bit floating point as output (the same codification of WAV files).

Comment: Ok.  Wondering why you are not in lossless mode as that mode implies bitwise compatibility.

Comment: I don't have lossless mode and I'm using the latest version of mac OS...

Comment: I have experienced a very quality augment with afplay -q 1, maybe those software and mode are using bitwise compatibility.